# How to extract an MP3 from a SWF in ActionScript 2.0

Tags: mp3, swfobject, directsound

I am in need of playing multiple sound files one after the other. The problem is that I cannot use MP3 due to firewall issues and must use a SWF with the sound embedded into it.

The problem is that the SWF will play the sound but not with the sound object - so I miss out on the built in features. I need to extract the Mp3 from the SWF to be able to play it with the sound object.

Is there a way to extract the MP3 that is embedded in the SWF using ActionScript 2?

Thank You for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this cannot be done. I ended up having to use a Delegate to mimic MP3 functionality using the SWF.